# piecewise function computation

Tags: c

input n, compute f(n) keeping exactly 2 digits after the decimal point.
[image: piecewise function]

example: input 5 output: 15.00

(Improvements / suggetions to the code below welcome)Here's what I 've come up with so far;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float m;

    scanf("%f", &m);
    if (m < 0)
        m = abs(m);

    else if (m < 2)
        m = sqrt(m + 1);

    else if (m < 4)
        m = pow(m + 2, 5);

    else if (m >= 4)
        m = (m * 2);
    m = m + 5;

    printf("%1.2f", m);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This code would probably be improved by having a separate `result` float, and then in each `if` statement, just set `result = abs(m)` or `result = 2 * m + 5` as appropriate, with `printf("%1.2f", result);` at the end.

Comment: Also, you should define a function `float f(float x) { ... }` that does the computation and then in main just have the `scanf` and `printf("%1.2f", f(m))`.

Comment: thanks a lot dbaupp, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use braces for all `if` blocks. That way you avoid mistakes like the one in your last case, which should be:

```
} else if (m >= 4) {
    m = (m * 2);
    m = m + 5;
}
```

or even better:

```
} else if (m >= 4) {
    m = (m * 2) + 5;
}
```

In addition, the first case can be written as:

```
if (m < 0) {
    m = -m;
} else if ...
```

although this is actually an optimization over the original formula and may or may not be more performant depending on the compiler and its options.

Answer (score 6):

Your last `if`-statement is wrong, must be

```
else if (m >= 4)
{
    m = (m * 2);
    m = m + 5;
}
```

Otherwise, `m = m + 5;` is out of the `if`'s "body" and will be executed in each situation (for all conditions)

Or, you can just write

```
else if (m >= 4)
    m = m * 2 + 5;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need braces around your last else

```
 else if (m >= 4) {
    m = (m * 2);
    m = m + 5;
 }
```

instead of

```
 else if (m >= 4)
    m = (m * 2);
m = m + 5;
```